# templets not found error in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am little bit confused about django templates, I have attached screen shot of workspace, can some one please tell how can I use addprofile.html template in my views.py in buddy app.
In my settings/base.py I have mentioned templates in following way:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: join(BASE_DIR, "directory")
BASE_DIR = dirname(dirname(dirname(__file__)))
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = [join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
MEDIA_ROOT = join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

# Use Django templates using the new Django 1.8 TEMPLATES settings

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            # insert more TEMPLATE_DIRS here

            join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates/')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I am new to Django and python and this is my first app in django

[image: my workspace]

Comment: try create another package 'buddy' inside templates package and move the htmls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create following structure:

buddy *(this is your existing budy app folder)*/templates *(this is existing folder)*/buddy *(this is new folder)*    and place all your templates: addprofile.html, edit_profile.html, show_profile.html, success.html withing this path.

edit your settings 'DIRS' so it looks as follows:

```
'DIRS': [
            join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates/'),
            join(BASE_DIR, 'buddy/templates')
```